# Best practice for using main form controls

Tags: vb.net, oop

So lets say I have a form1 that opens on startup. Form1 contains a textbox named textbox1 and a button named button1. When I click button1 this is code that is called:

```
Class form1

    Sub CapLetters () 'buttons click event

       Dim myObj as new MyObject

       MyObj.CapAllLetters
       Textbox1.text = MyObj.GetThoseCapLetters

    End sub

End class
```

Now, I know this is kinda dumb, but my main question is, since im creating a new object, the textbox1 will not be available in my object unless I specifically call it like:

```
Form1.textbox1.text
```

Is this good practice or is there a better way? Now in my program I have about 10 textbox and comboboxs I need my object to use. I know i could do something like this:

```
MyObj.CapAllLetters (textbox1.text)
```

But that doesn't seem like a good idea to pass that many values in a method.

I think I need a way for my object to gather all the info upon initating it?

Thoughts?

Comment: What does TextBox1 have to do with `CapLetters()`?  The `MyObj` created there only lasts as long as that method is running

Comment: I get the code doesnt make much sense but my question is still valid, what is the best way to reference all my controls on form1 in my created object?

Comment: You dont need a class for that, just a loop

Comment: Ok, obviously my code is a very generic idea of what im trying to do, and yes there is a much simpler approach, but my code is actually much more complex than what i tried to show here, i was just simply demonstrating by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically seem to be asking whether it's OK to use the default instance of a form.  The answer is yes.  In recent versions of VB, each form that has a parameterless constructor also has a default instance, which is a single instance that can be accessed anywhere and at any time via the class name.  This feature exists because it makes it easier for beginners to access forms from different places in a project without having to worry about passing references to forms around that project.

In the case of the startup form in a project, it is always the default instance of its type, assuming that you haven't disabled the application framework.  That means that you can always access your startup form anywhere in your project using the default instance of its type.

Now, you'll find that experienced developers rarely use default instances.  That's because they are never required and rarely add value if you know what you're doing.  That means that you can always access your application's startup form is reasonable locations throughout your project without using the default instance.

Comment: One question regarding the "experienced developers rarely use default instances", if they don't use the default instance, how do they get the data easily passed to the object? I'm not sure why I have such a hard time understanding something that is probably simple, but i am. I almost think it would be easiest, if upon creating an object it would go gather all the data I need to work with, maybe by creating a method to do so, or maybe a better way?

Comment: Forms are just objects like any other, so you get data into and out of them like any other objects.  How you get specific data in specific situations depends on the specifics of that situation, so I can't give you one answer that covers everything.

Comment: As an example though, let's say that you have an MDI application where clicking a button in one child form is supposed to make something happen in another child form. In that case, the children would know nothing about each other but the parent would know about both, having created both. The child with the button would raise an event that would be handled by the parent and the parent would then call a method in the second child and that child would then make happen whatever needed to happen. The first child could pass data to the parent via the event and the parent to the second child.